# Trying to install Sony software PlayMemories Home

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, sony

I am running 16.04. I'm trying to install Sony software called PlayMemories Home. The old program is no longer available. This is their file/picture transfer software for my camera. I just reinstalled Ubuntu. How do I install this program on ubuntu 16.04? I have seen the PMB program that sony use to use for their older cameras. I have an older camera but PMB will not load.

Comment: Could you please update your question with the exact steps you are following, and what happens / goes wrong ?

Comment: Hello  Jeff, and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. In order to increase that chances that somebody gives a good answer to your question, the first thing to do is ask a question; you should edit your post and actually include a question. You should also clarify the context: who gives that error message? When does it give that error message? What are you doing in order to make that error message appear? Is the error message unexpected?